# Slowly scroll to a specific div or anchor in a html page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, anchor, autoscroll

I have an html page and I want to make it scroll slowly to a specific point or all around the page. I tried the following codes but nothing worked:

```
<a href="#anchorName"></a>

<script>

function scrollTo(hash) 
{
    location.hash = "#anchorName";
}

</script>
```

Secondly, I tried scrolling to a div but in this case I also had to use CSS and put a height. I am trying to avoid that.

As seen on stackoverflow past issues :

```
<a href="#myDiv" id="button">button</a>

<script>

    $("#button").click(function() 
    {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });

</script>
```

and it did not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  margin-top: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#myDiv" id="button">button</a>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: It works. Is it possible to change the speed and make it scroll a  bit slower?

Comment: Sure. just change the speed in the animate function. Actually its 2000ms. So change this value like you want.

Comment: I tried changing that and nothing changed. It now works. I needed a refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting `#myDiv` as href for the button, you have to [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) before you trigger the animation:

```js
$("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="myDiv" id="button">button</a>
<div style="height:400px;"></div>
<div id="myDiv">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do a  Smooth scroll to some component id  by following the example codes  using jQuery, for example :

```
<a class="move_to_div" href="#anchorName"> move div </a>


<div id="anchorName"> </div> 


<script>
 $(".move_to_div").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#anchorName").offset().top
   }, 1000);
 });

</script>
```

this is just example , when click on 'a href link' the scrolldown will be smooth (to test the result add some space between a link and div by using css )
i hop this helpful for you  .